# how to send json data to api with data mode params in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, httprequest, webclient

how to send json data to api with data mode `params` in windows phone

```
"url":"
http://rawafedtech.info/tafsir/stable-api/current/web/app_dev.php/dummy/home
","method":"POST","headers":"",
"data":[{"key":"token","value":"1m1","type":"text"},{"key":"pageNo","value":"1","type":"text"},{"key":"pagesize","value":"20","type":"text"}]
,"dataMode":"params"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: 'json' 
e.g.
`$http({
       url: "your url",
       method: 'POST',
       data: "your json object",
       dataType: 'json',
})`

Comment: i want this using c# wp8